# Python/Apache WSGI Application, app broken (500s) after failed plugin install

Tags: python, wsgi

Firstly, I've asked this on the MediaDrop forum, however had no response (it's quite low traffic). It appears it could just be my specific mis-understanding of Python and WSGI rather than MediaDrop specific so that's why I'm now asking here.

We're evaluating MediaDrop for use and have (well, had) it up and running under Apache in WSGI mode in a sandbox VM.

This is my first exposure to Python so I'm a bit in the dark on what's happened and how to fix this. I'm a PHP guy normally.

Firstly I got this up and running under Apache on RHEL6.4 in WSGI mode. The VM is running Python 2.6.6.

FYI, the documentation says the mediacore.wsgi file is in a specific location in the install tarball, but it's actually not there. I found it on GitHub, and used it to proceed with the install. Probably not related to this issue however.

At the request of the BA, I downloaded the Mediacore Panda plugin. It's install failed because it couldn't reach some external sources to download some files. I didn't keep the logs because we decided in the end not to evaluate the plugin because it uses Amazon S3, and we want to host everything locally.

Now after that, Mediadrop is broken and only ever returns a 500 internal server error. I have grepped the code of Mediadrop to see if the Panda install left some debris behind, but I can't see any. The instances I do find are:

```
grep -Ri panda *
deployment.ini:# plugins = editviews, panda, seo
doc/dev/plugins.rst:created a cloud on
pandastream.com <http://pandastream.com/>
_ with
doc/dev/plugins.rst:your Panda Stream account.
doc/dev/plugins.rst:Click Add New engine > Panda Transcoding and Storage. You can also select which
doc/dev/plugins.rst:**2. Panda Storage Engine Fields**
doc/dev/plugins.rst:**3. Panda Account Details**
doc/dev/plugins.rst: Login to your PandaStream account, and at the dashboard click on your cloud.
doc/dev/plugins.rst: This is your PandaStream API Access Key. Login into PandaStream, and click
doc/dev/plugins.rst:when creating your Panda Stream Encoding Cloud. You can also enter any
mediacore/lib/auth/pylons_glue.py: # using the FunctionProtector as a decorator (e.g. in the panda plugin)
mediacore/config/deployment.ini_tmpl:# plugins = editviews, panda, seo
mediacore/public/scripts/third-party/squeezebox-1.1-rc4-yui-compressed.js: * SqueezeBox - Expandable Lightbox
mediacore/public/scripts/third-party/squeezebox-1.1-rc4.js: * SqueezeBox - Expandable Lightbox
mediacore/public/styles/third-party/squeezebox-1.1-rc4.css: * SqueezeBox - Expandable Lightbox
```

Grep-fu wasn't great but you get the idea...
I read that a touch of the mediacore.wsgi file will trigger a recompile of the Python code as it sees the new modification date, I hope that is correct, but I also restarted Apache (a few times) for good measure. No luck.
The exception in the Apache logs is:

```
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] mod_wsgi (pid=10464): Target WSGI script '/opt/MediaCore-0.10.3/mediacore.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] mod_wsgi (pid=10464): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/MediaCore-0.10.3/mediacore.wsgi'.
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/opt/MediaCore-0.10.3/mediacore.wsgi", line 18, in <module>
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] application = loadapp('config:'+deployment_config)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 204, in loadapp
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 225, in loadobj
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] return context.create()
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 625, in create
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] return self.object_type.invoke(self)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 110, in invoke
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/util/fixtypeerror.py", line 57, in fix_call
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] val = callable(*args, **kw)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/opt/MediaCore-0.10.3/mediacore/config/middleware.py", line 289, in make_app
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] config = load_environment(global_conf, app_conf)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/opt/MediaCore-0.10.3/mediacore/config/environment.py", line 41, in load_environment
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] plugin_mgr = PluginManager(config)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/opt/MediaCore-0.10.3/mediacore/plugin/__init__.py", line 50, in __init__
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] module = epoint.load()
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/opt/mediadrop_venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2047, in load
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] if require: self.require(env, installer)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/opt/mediadrop_venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2060, in require
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer)))
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/opt/mediadrop_venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 588, in resolve
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] raise DistributionNotFound(req)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:13 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] DistributionNotFound: panda==0.1.2
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] mod_wsgi (pid=10465): Target WSGI script '/opt/MediaCore-0.10.3/mediacore.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] mod_wsgi (pid=10465): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/MediaCore-0.10.3/mediacore.wsgi'.
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/opt/MediaCore-0.10.3/mediacore.wsgi", line 18, in <module>
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] application = loadapp('config:'+deployment_config)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 204, in loadapp
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 225, in loadobj
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] return context.create()
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 625, in create
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] return self.object_type.invoke(self)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 110, in invoke
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/util/fixtypeerror.py", line 57, in fix_call
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] val = callable(*args, **kw)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/opt/MediaCore-0.10.3/mediacore/config/middleware.py", line 289, in make_app
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] config = load_environment(global_conf, app_conf)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/opt/MediaCore-0.10.3/mediacore/config/environment.py", line 41, in load_environment
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] plugin_mgr = PluginManager(config)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/opt/MediaCore-0.10.3/mediacore/plugin/__init__.py", line 50, in __init__
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] module = epoint.load()
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/opt/mediadrop_venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2047, in load
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] if require: self.require(env, installer)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/opt/mediadrop_venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2060, in require
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer)))
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File "/opt/mediadrop_venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 588, in resolve
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] raise DistributionNotFound(req)
[Fri Apr 04 11:27:14 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] DistributionNotFound: panda==0.1.2
```

So, what am I missing here? I'd rather not blow this install away and start again if I don't have to.

Comment: Did I leave some information out? Is there something else I can add to help? Really would appreciate some suggestions here...

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance it is a bug, I would download `pylint` and run it on the wsgi application to ensure there are no errors.

```
pylint /opt/MediaCore-0.10.3/mediacore.wsgi
```

You can also pipe that command to `grep "E"` to quickly look for error lines. (pylint will not autocomplete on `.wsgi` files, you will need to specify them explicitly on the command line.)

Edit: Also, please verify that your wsgi plugin is python 2.6 compatible. If the plugin is python3 or python 2.7+, that could explain the errors. 
Also, do you have the libapache2-mod-wsgi plugin installed? (Not sure if that is the exact name for redhat)